# trouble with a checkbox on the user registration pages

Tags: 7, users

I created an extra checkbox field for the user registration form

This is the field setting page. (*Standaardwaarde* means "Default value.")

[image: screenshot]

In the setting page, the field is unchecked, but it's checked in the registration page. I looked at some older questions regarding this subject, but it still a big questions mark for me.

How can I get the checkbox to be unchecked by default?

Comment: Did you checked the 'Default value' for the field?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: I created a Boolean field, and it is not automatically checked, when the default value is unchecked.

Comment: Default value = Standaardwaarde (see picture)
This is the place to set this? right?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The problem was that I selected the wrong field type. I think because it is only one field you need to select a Boolean type. Now it's working!