# Textfield value not saving to database

Tags: forms

I am having a problem with saving values of a textfield in the database.

Usecase:
Users with a certain role should add two things on their accountpage the first time they login.
1.change their password
2.agree with terms.

Point 2 is the trouble part.
I have a text field with two values:
'Agree' and 'Not agree'
Now i like to hide the second option but with my current code the value of the agree option is not getting saved to the database.

Help appreciated
Thanks

Used code

```
<?php
function regform_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state,  $form_id) {
  global $user;
 // Making password required when role=In between role.
if( ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') and (isset($form['account']['pass'])) and (in_array('In between role', array_values($user->roles))) ){
    $form['account']['pass']['#type'] = 'password';
    $form['account']['pass']['#required'] = TRUE;
    $form['account']['pass']['#type'] = 'password_confirm';
    $form['account']['pass']['#required'] = TRUE;

   // Disabling and hiding 'Dont agree field' field

  $form['field_agree'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => array(
   'Agree' => t('Agree'),
   'Do not agree' => t('Do not agree'),

 ),
);
hide($form['field_agree']['Do not agree']);         
 }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Have a read of [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767), it'll answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to hide the 'no' option from checkbox - just go the the field settings and make it a single on/off checkbox, that way you will not have to deal with this at all.

Then, go to the field settings and set the Default value to off (see screenshot).
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. This gives me a single checkbox that is checked by default. Do you have any thoughts on how to get this checkbox unchecked by default?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: My default value as you have displayed it in your screenshot is set to 'off'. However this still doesn't give me an unchecked box on the  user account page. For some reason this 'default setting' is not respected.

Comment: solved now: my solution is:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51387/trouble-with-a-checkbox-on-the-user-registration-pages